# Apache Camel: handling unix file permission errors wrapped in GenericFileOperationFailedException

Tags: apache-camel

Here's the problem I've been grappling with for a while...I'm using Camel (v2.10.2) to set up many file routes to move data across file systems, servers, and in/out of the organisation (B2B). There are data and signal files in their respective dirs with some of the routes being short lived, while others run as services on different VMs/servers. These processes (routes) are run under different unix 'functional' ids, but there is an attempt to make them belong to the same unix group(s) if possible...

Of course on unix there is always the potential for file/dir permission problems...and that is the issue I'm facing/trying to solve.

I use the `DefaultErrorHandler` and log success or failure for an exchange via a custom `RoutePolicy` within the `onExchangeDone(...)` checking the `Exchange.isFailed()`. The signal file is either moved to the destination on success or moved to `.error` dir on fail, with an alert written to a system-wide alert log (checked by Tivoli)

The file route is configured to propagate errors occurring while picking up files, etc via the `consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true`

Basically, if I have any unix permission related errors, then I want to stop (and maybe remove) the effected route, indicating clearly that this has happened and why - a permission issue is not easily solvable programmatically, so stop and alert is the only option.

So I'll illustrate a test case that causes an issue...

App_A creates some data files in **./data/**. Then App_A creates the same number of signal files in **./signal/**, but due to some 'data' related bug it also creates a signal file  **./signal/acc_xyz.csv** that doesn't have a corresponding data file.

Route starts to process **./signal/acc_xyz.csv** and the 'validation process' finds that **./data/acc_xyz.csv** doesn't exist and throws an exception to indicate this, hence stopping the exchange being processed further.

The `File` component is configured with `moveFailed=.error` to move the signal file to **./signal/.error/**, but this dir is locked (don't worry why this is) to the functional user id executing the Java process and internal Camel processing throws a `GenericFileOperationFailedException` indicating the cause to be an underlying '**Permission denied**' issue.

Oh dear, the same signal file is then processed again, and again, and...

I have tried to get this 'secondary error' propagated to my code, but have failed, hence I can't stop the route.

How can I get this and other internal Camel errors propagated to my code/exception handler/whatever and not just seeing it be logged and swallowed?

thanks in advance

ok more detail from log4j...note the sequence of times

**Camel DefaultErrorHandler:**

```
2013-04-25 15:06:26,001 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file:///FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal] ERROR (MarkerIgnoringBase.java:161) - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-rwld601-rw-discoverfinancial-com-60264-1366902384246-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-rwld601-rw-discoverfinancial-com-60264-1366902384246-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missingFile: route [App_A.outboundReceipt] has missing file at /FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/data/stuff.log
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missingFile: route [App_A.outboundReceipt] has missing file at /FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/data/stuff.log
        at com.myco.mft.process.BaseFileRouteBuilder.checkFile(BaseFileRouteBuilder.java:934)
```

**My alert logger via the RoutePolicy.onExchangeDone(...) - at this pont the exchange has completed with a failure:**

```
2013-04-25 15:06:26,011|Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file:///FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal|exchange|App_A.outboundReceipt|signalFile=/FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal/stuff.log|there has been a routing failure|missingFile: route [App_A.outboundReceipt] has missing file at /FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/data/stuff.log
```

**Camel endpoint post-processing - this is the stuff that Camel doesn't propagate to me:**

```
2013-04-25 15:06:26,027 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file:///FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal] WARN  (GenericFileOnCompletion.java:149) - Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileDeleteProcessStrategy@104e28b for file: GenericFile[/FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal/stuff.log]
2013-04-25 15:06:28,038 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file:///FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal] WARN  (MarkerIgnoringBase.java:136) - Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Error renaming file from /FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal/stuff.log to /FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal/.error/stuff.log]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Error renaming file from /FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal/stuff.log to /FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal/.error/stuff.log
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.renameFile(FileOperations.java:72)
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /FTROOT/fileTransfer/outbound/signal/stuff.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

Comment: File is being polled again and again because it is unmoved and hence, still existing in the location. I guess you'll have to get hold of the route (possibly from the context) and call stop method over it from within the exception handler.

Comment: @U2one: that's exactly what I want to do, except Camel doesn't seem to propagte the - I'll call it secondary or internal - exception that wraps the IO permissions issue...here's a log4j error trace - note the times

Comment: ok not a feature in v2.X maybe in v3.x...seems like a fairly fundamental feature that's required... more here [catch Exception thrown by ScheduledPollConsumer](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/catch-Exception-thrown-by-ScheduledPollConsumer-tp3409483p3409512.html)...but in the meantime the file:// URI requires `&consumer.exceptionHandler=#myExceptionHandler` to be set - I missed this even though I read it umpteen times :¬(